# Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long';

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Tengo un error en SpringBoot, es un simple CRUD. Me pasa al apretar "Eliminar" en la vista. Lo elimina cuando veo la BD, pero tira error. El error completo es:

Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "listar"
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "listar"

La vista es la siguiente:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="layout/layout :: head">
</head>
</head>
<body>
 <header th:replace="layout/layout :: header"></header> 
 
 <div class="container">
  <h1 th:text="${titulo}"></h1>
  <table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Id</th> 
     <th>Nombre</th>
     <th>Apellido</th>
     <th>E-Mail</th>
     <th>Fecha alta</th>
     <th>Borrar</th>
     <th>Editar</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr th:each="cliente:${clientes}">
     <td th:text="${cliente.id}"></td>
     <td th:text="${cliente.nombre}"></td>
     <td th:text="${cliente.apellido}"></td>
     <td th:text="${cliente.email}"></td>
     <td th:text="${cliente.fecha}"></td>
     <td><a th:href="@{/eliminar/} + ${cliente.id}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" th:text="Eliminar"></a></td> 
     <td><a th:href="@{/editar/} + ${cliente.id}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" th:text="Editar"></a></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
 
 <footer th:replace="layout/layout :: footer"></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Mientras que el controlador es:

```js
package com.nestor.spring.app.jpa.controller;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus;

import com.nestor.spring.app.jpa.models.entity.Cliente;
import com.nestor.spring.app.jpa.models.service.ClienteService;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("cliente")
public class ClienteController {
 
 @Autowired
 private ClienteService clienteService;
 
 @GetMapping("/listar")
 public String listar(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("titulo","Listar clientes");
  model.addAttribute("clientes",clienteService.listar());
  return "listar";
  
 }

 @GetMapping("/form")
 public String crearCliente(Model model) {
  Cliente cliente=new Cliente();
  model.addAttribute("titulo", "Crear cliente");
  model.addAttribute("cliente", cliente);
  return "form";
 }
 
 @PostMapping("/form")
 public String guardarCliente(@Valid Cliente cliente, BindingResult result, Model model, SessionStatus status) {
  
  if(result.hasErrors()){
   model.addAttribute("titulo", "formulario cliente");
   return "form";
  }
  clienteService.alta(cliente);
  status.setComplete();
  return "redirect:listar";
 }
 
 @GetMapping("/editar/{id}")
 public String editar(@PathVariable(value="id") Long id, Model model){
  
  Cliente cliente=null;
  
  if(id>0 && id!=null) {
   cliente=clienteService.buscarPorId(id);
  }else {
   return "redirect:listar";
  }
  
  model.addAttribute("titulo","Editar cliente");
  model.addAttribute("cliente", cliente);
  return "form";
 }
 
 @GetMapping("/eliminar/{id}")
 public String eliminarCliente(@PathVariable(value="id") Long id) {
   clienteService.baja(id);
   return "redirect:listar";
 }
 
}
```

```js
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;


@Entity
@Table(name="clientes")
public class Cliente {
 
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;
 
 @NotEmpty
 private String nombre;
 
 @NotEmpty
 private String apellido;
 
 @NotEmpty
 @Email
 private String email;
 
 
 @NotNull
 @Column(name="fecha_alta")
 @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
 @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
 private Date fecha;
 
 public String getEmail() {
  return email;
 }
 public void setEmail(String email) {
  this.email = email;
 }
 
 public Long getId() {
  return id;
 }
 public void setId(Long id) {
  this.id = id;
 }
 public String getNombre() {
  return nombre;
 }
 public void setNombre(String nombre) {
  this.nombre = nombre;
 }
 public String getApellido() {
  return apellido;
 }
 public void setApellido(String apellido) {
  this.apellido = apellido;
 }
 public Date getFecha() {
  return fecha;
 }
 public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
  this.fecha = fecha;
 }
 
 

}
```

Me estoy volviendo loco. Desde ya muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Probablemente se deba a que tu id sea de tipo Long y requieras String. Coloca el código de tu Bean para entender mejor el problema.

Comment: Cuando se genera la acción del botón eliminar esto va algún archivo JS ? donde haces el submit al controlador?

Comment: No, no va ningún JS.

Comment: Agregué la entidad para que puedan verlo.

Comment: Intenta agregando el slash en el return de la siguiente manera:
return "redirect:/listar";

Answer (score 2):

Finalmente pude solucionarlo. Faltaba un "/" en el return. Muchas gracias a todos los que se tomaron la molestia. Sería **return "redirect:/listar";**